# Diffrent outputs caused by a " irrelevant " statement in graph construction (symbolic style programs ) in tensorflow

Tags: python, graph, tensorflow, construction

I have a basic issue about the symbolic style programs in tensorflow, below are codes ( tensorflow 0.12 ):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sys

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, 1)
y = 1
z = x + y * 2
# x = z

with tf.Session() as sess:
for i in range(2):
    result = sess.run([z], feed_dict={x: [1]})
    print "result = "
    print result[0]
```

if the 'x = z' is commented, this is a typical directed acyclic graph (DAG), the result is:

```
 result = 
 [ 3.]
 result = 
 [ 3.]
```

if the 'x = z' is uncommented, the result is:

```
 result = 
 [ 1.]
 result = 
 [ 1.]
```

I think the result should be irrelevant of the statement "x = z", and the result should be 3. What caused the diffrence? Thank you!

Comment: when you uncomment # x = z, you are feeding [1] into a different node in the graph in your `feed_dict`

Comment: Dear Yaroslav, much thanks to you !  i understand it now, when x=z is added, the  x  acually indicates the same graph node with z, when if x is feeding [1], so z is also [1].  Can you help me on another issue in below link ? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317636/how-to-make-the-generated-data-of-remote-worker-span-iterations-in-in-graph-repl)

Answer (score 0):

when x=z is added, the x acually indicates the same graph node with z, when if x is feeding [1], so z is also [1]. Thanks Yaroslav.